# Can we conclude, that if $f,g$ are measurable and $f=g+h$, then $h$ must be measurable, too?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$ be a measurable space and $f,g:\Omega\to[0,\infty]$ be $\mathcal A$-$\mathcal B([0,\infty])$-measurable. Can we conclude, that if $$f=g+h$$ for some $h:\Omega\to[0,\infty]$, then $h$ must be $\mathcal A$-$\mathcal B([0,\infty])$-measurable, too?

---

Clearly, the statement would be true, when $f(\Omega),g(\Omega)\subseteq [0,\infty)$, since in that case we could write $$h=f-g\;,$$ but I don't know how we can argue in the general case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not true.

Consider $g \equiv \infty$ and $h(x) = \infty$ for $x \in A$, $h(x) = 0$ for $x \notin A$, where $A$ is not measurable. Then $h$ is not measurable, but

$$
f = g+h \equiv \infty
$$
is measurable and $g$ is also.

In fact, you can choose $h : X \to [0,\infty]$ arbitrary in the above.

Comment: What if we assume $f(\Omega)\subseteq[0,\infty)$ (and let only $g$ remain arbitrary)?

Comment: @0xbadf00d: Well, if $g(x) = \infty$ **or** $h(x) = \infty$ for some $x$, this would imply $f(x) = \infty$ (because of $g,h \geq 0$), which your assumption excludes. Thus, your new assumption implies that $f,g,h$ are all real valued. Thus, you can again write $h = f-g$ and be done.